# How to config volumes in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

Is a very simple question I guess, but I could not find an answer.
This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  db: 
  nextcloud:
```

The question is, I want to specify the value of "db" or "nextcloud" in "volumes", and reference them in "Services".like this

```
services:
  db:
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  nextcloud:
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
volumes:
  db: /home/roj/DataDisk/nextcloud-insecure/db
  nextcloud: /home/roj/DataDisk/nextcloud-insecure/disk
```

but I got problem`ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume 'db' must be a mapping not a string.`

how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

The top-level `volumes` section is not meant to specify mounts but volume driver configuration (see [official documention](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference) on that matter). *ie.* this is incorrect

```yml
volumes:
  db: /home/roj/DataDisk/nextcloud-insecure/db # incorrect
  nextcloud: /home/roj/DataDisk/nextcloud-insecure/disk # incorrect
```

If you want to mount host directories to you container, you must specify it in the `volumes` section of your `services`, *eg.*

```yml
services:
  db:
    volumes:
      - /home/roj/DataDisk/nextcloud-insecure/db:/var/lib/mysql
  nextcloud:
    volumes:
      - /home/roj/DataDisk/nextcloud-insecure/disk:/var/www/html
```

See [official documentation on services volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) for more information on that.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax in the outer `volumes` instruction is incorrect.

If you want to mount to a docker-managed volume, do this:

```
services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    volumes:
      - db:/app

volumes:
  db:
```

If you want to mount to a local path, do this (you can replace the dot in `.:/app` with any other local path, like: `/home/you:/server/path`):

```
services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

If it starts with a dot or a slash, it will be treated as a path, otherwise, as a docker-managed named volume.

These are the common usage patterns, but you can read more about [volumes in compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) for some additional information.